# Is it possible to adjust the weights of a pymatching graph after it is created?

Tags: error-correction, pymatching

I'd like to adjust the characteristics of a pymatching graph (specifically the edge weights of individual edges) to explore the effects on the decoding process.

While the `pymatching.Matching` has an `.add_edge()` method to add an edge, I cannot find anything to adjust parameters of existing edges or remove an edge (to then replace it with the add method). I'm curious if there is any way of doing this without having to create a whole new `Matching` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

```python
>>> import pymatching
>>> m = pymatching.Matching()
>>> m.add_edge(1, 2, weight=2)
>>> m.edges()
[(1, 2, {'fault_ids': set(), 'weight': 2.0, 'error_probability': -1.0})]
>>> m.add_edge(1,2,weight=3, merge_strategy='replace')
>>> m.edges()
[(1, 2, {'fault_ids': set(), 'weight': 3.0, 'error_probability': -1.0})]
```

Comment: Ah! The `merge_strategy=` argument is what I was looking for then. Thanks!